# Integrals: Noob Question

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

So I have a "noob" understanding of calculus. In an integral, I forget, while I realize the limits of the two, what value does the upper and lower limit have in the equation to finding the $d/dx$ or derivative? More specifically I have a small example:

$y = mx + b$

$y = f(x)$

$f(x) = \dfrac{8}{5} x + 2$

The upper limit is $5$ and the lower limit is $0$. The integral is
$$\int_0^5 \frac{8}{5} x + 2.$$
I know
$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
is the derivative. But I don't see where the upper and lower limit is being used! Please explain.

Comment: Derivative $\ne$ **anti** derivative.  Which do you mean?

Comment: like i said, I'm a noob. VERY NEW. I only know about Integration and Differentiation, not about negative derivatives and different types of Integrals. I can't be any more specific. It's more of a General question for what the lower and upper limits in an Integral play a role in and what you do with them. Do they just sit there? Or what?

Comment: In computing definite integrals using antiderivatives one plugs the upper and lower bounds in via the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: ok that works, but I mean, say you have a line you are trying to find the area below it down to the axis, you want to find the area within the x range of 0-5 (The mentioned Integral in my question) and all of a sudden you want to find the area of the x range 0-10, obviously 0-5 is not going to be the same answer as 0-10

Comment: @Link: Ofcourse you're a programmer. Your vocabulary and formatting all converge to that point.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer I'll scan in my calculus notes for you, too.

Comment: @alvonellos you have been very helpful to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of a function $f(x)$ from $x = a$ to $x = b$, written as $$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$ is the signed area between the graph of the function $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis, from $x = a$ to $x = b$, as can be seen in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aIntegral_example.svg) image.

One half of the fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ (i.e. $F'(x) = f(x)$) then $$\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b) - F(a).$$ So, when presented with such an integral, you must first find an antiderivate (presumably using the laws you have learnt/are learning) then evaluate the antiderivative at the upper limit and subtract from that the value of the antiderivative at the lower limit.

Comment: so, correct me if I'm wrong,  substitute (Integral) a-b x^2 with:

Comment: a-b (b^2+1)/2+1 = -d/dx and vice versa for the derivative?

Comment: Forget about derivatives. Integrals are integrals are integrals; when solving integrals you may use techniques involving derivatives, but on a day-to-day basis you can treat them as entirely unrelated objects. In any case, your calculation is not correct. In the example you gave, $f(x)=x^2$, so $F(x)=x^3/3$; can you use Michael's answer to find $\int_a^b f(x)dx$?

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! :) Onward on my calculus journey... something,something, f(PI) = ?x + 1, something, f(e), f(FI), something, Infinity = ?  I'm 13 just so you know :)

Comment: Don't tell people your age unless they ask. It causes annoyance at best and at worst you might cause somebody with severe anxiety a great deal of pain.

Comment: right... I'll keep my age with discretion.